# Unsure how to store this code correctly

Tags: php, variables

The best way to describe my website is to simply give you a link so that you can look at it:  http://opensourcewebsite.host22.com/editpage.php. Basically, this is a website that people who are learning how to design websites can go on and test their code.  I already know that in the sites current state, it is very susceptible to various attacks.  Note that this is not the finished site.  Users will enter their code in the textare and when the submit button is clicked, the code is saved in a php variable which is then displayed on the web page.  Currently you can use html code, css, and javascript code and have it display correctly.

My problem is that I want the user to be able to enter php code in the textarea and have it display the results on the webpage.  Feel free to go to my site and enter code to get a feel for how the page works.  When you enter php code you get something similar to the following:

When you enter

```
<?php $hi = "hello"; ?>
<?php echo '<p>$hi</p>' ?>
```

it will show the following in the source code

```
<!--?php $hi = "hello" ?-->
<!--?php echo '<p-->$hi<p></p>' ?&gt;
```

The below code is how I echo the source code in the text area

```
<div id="editArea"><?php echo stripslashes($source_code) ?></div>
```

Is it even possible to store php code in a php variable? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked out http://codepad.org/?

Comment: I just took a look, that is the idea of the site.  As of right now this is more of a personal growth project that probably won't go anywhere.  Thank you for the link though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally, if you want it to execute as code, use `eval($code);`

Though, I have to say what you are doing sounds extremely dangerous.

Comment: What I am planning on doing is have a login system so that only 1 user will be able to edit the code.  Other users will be able to view the code but will not be able to edit it.  The idea of the site is similar to this one in that people with an issue can post the code and others can view it along with the output and suggest changes in the comments. Then the original poster can edit the code until they are satisfied with the output.

Comment: What happens when a user decides to do what Dagon wrote?

Comment: I have decided that this site would be too risky to use at the moment, and will be used for person growth and developemnt.  Thank you all for the suggestions!